# Recharts: Responsive LineChart grid and line not rendering properly, appears off chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

So I created a LineChart with `Recharts 1.8.5` but it seems that the domain of the YAxis doesn't render properly, the max number of my data on the YAxis is **1688** but only reaches 1000 in the chart. [This is my json data](https://pastebin.com/UAGr5vA8).

```
  <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} height={500}>
    <LineChart
      data={this.props.data}
      margin={{ top: 100 }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey={"fecha"} />
      <YAxis domain={[0, "dataMax + 1000"]} />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Line dataKey="confirmados" 
            stroke="#8884d8" 
            layout="horizontal" 
            strokeWidth={3} />
    </LineChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>;
```

[image: LineChart]

If I add `domain={[0, 'dataMax + 1000']}` that fixes the problem, but doesn't look normal to have 1000 units, or 100 added after my last number, and also the grid seems disproportional.

[image]

If I remove the margin, the line just disappears and gets cut off:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to add `dataKey="confirmados"` to your `YAxis`?

Comment: @Shlang Yes, I get the same result as the last image. The only thing that seems to fix it is to set the domain to a higher number than my dataMax, but I don't think this is the way to fix it.

Comment: Okay, seems that the problem is in the fact your "confirmados" values are strings and the chart is not trying to parse them as numbers but just shows something weird. I've made an [example with a fix](https://jsfiddle.net/nhsmeoqv/1/)

Comment: @Shlang Thanks that fixed my issue. I was under the assumption Recharts would be able to chart anything regardless of their type, because it seems it was charting the data, but the line was going off chart for some reason.